# Docker set container IP addr from DHCP/DNS automatically

Tags: dns, network-programming, docker, production, dhclient

While I found few options to force docker containers to have IP addr that match my DNS, I did not found any method to enforce a permanent IP addr automatically at "docker start".

Currently I have a small script that retrieves IP addrs from my DNS and config container's network directly from docker host. Unfortunately this method does not work with automatic start, preventing usage of tools like docker-ui.

My script is available at https://gist.github.com/fulup-bzh/8fd32c8cde9a1e5ec971 The script works fine, but I would like this to happen automatic in order to enable users to leverage tools like "docker-ui"

Question: 
 - is there a way to force the execution of an "autostart" script at host level during "docker start" execution ?
 - alternatively is there is way to set container IP from DHCP automatically from the host ?

Comment: Did you try taking a look at the network documentation and especially the docker0 interface documentation ? https://docs.docker.com/articles/networking/

Comment: If you found something in the documentation that can help, please point to it. I checked multiple time all the documentation I could find with no success